# PHP array_walk_recursive: two approaches, different result

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, global

Given the following setup:

```
    $storer = array();
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3);
```

I'm curious why this does not write to `$storer`...

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($val, $key) {
    global $storer;
    $storer[] = 'foo';
});
print_r($storer); //no change - empty
```

..but this does:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($val, $key) use (&$storer) {
    $storer[] = 'foo';
});
print_r($storer); //three items, all 'foo'
```

Can anyone enlighten me? In a user function I would expect `global` to provide read/write access.

Comment: I tried the first approach [in a sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5a1f3106c872fa42e045db6f84a892a6e17c90b) and it looks like it works as expected, it prints 3 foos.

Comment: Both functions write `foo` three times, are you developing locally? If so, try and restart Apache. If externally, try uploading the file again, might be something temporary that's failing.

Comment: Is the statement '$storer = array();' really in the global scope i.e. not inside a function. Try print_r( array_key_exists( 'storer', $GLOBALS ) ) - This should return true. If not try print_r( debug_backtrace( DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS ) ) - This will give you your call stack from which you can determine your scope.

Comment: Aha, I think I might have deduced from the comments what's happening. `$storer` is not truly global; it's in the outer scope. All of this is in a class method...

Answer (score 2):

After pulling my hair out trying to get a **flattened array with keys** this works:

```
$result = array();

array_walk_recursive($inputarray,function($v, $k) use (&$result){ $result[$k] = $v;  });

$inputarray = $result;
```

I hope someone finds this and it helps.